# What are the hex values of the Google logo colors?

Tags: colors

Not sure if this would be the right place to ask, but I would like to know the hex values of the colors used in the Google logo.

Comment: I thought one of the answers would at least show the gentleman where to find and how to use a colour-picker.  Something about a feeding a fish for a day, so it can teach a man to eat...  ;)

Comment: I recently got an email with official Google signature that has Google colours and I inspected the html code and got these values from it:

Red: rgb(213,15,37) or Hex #d50f25
Blue: rgb(51,105,232) or Hex #3369e8
Green: rgb(0,153,57) or Hex #009939
Yellow rgb(238,178,17) or Hex #eeb211

Comment: The Google logo has changed and the accepted answer is now out of date. The correct answer (with official source) is [ecdani's](http://superuser.com/a/629040/73337).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It varies a bit, since the logo is shaded/antialiased, but these values are pretty close:

- Blue: #0266C8
- Red: #F90101
- Yellow: #F2B50F
- Green: #00933B

Answer (score 13):

I see here:
https://sites.google.com/site/studentchromebook/event-resources-and-calendar/event-planning-print-materials

**Blue**

- Pantone: C 300 U 3005
- CMYK C: 100 44 0 0
- CMYK U: 100 34 0 2
- Hex: 3369E8
- RGB: 51 105 232

**Red**

- Pantone: C 199 U 199
- CMYK: 0 100 62 0
- Hex: D50F25
- RGB: 213 15 37

**Yellow**

- Pantone: C 123 U 109
- CMYK C: 0 24 94 0
- CMYK U: 0 16 100 0
- Hex: EEB211
- RGB: 238 178 17

**Green**

- Pantone: C 362 U 362
- CMYK: 70 0 100 9
- Hex: 009925
- RGB: 0 153 37

**Gray (Secondary)**

- Pantone: C 403 U 403
- CMYK: 0 0 0 65
- Hex: 666666
- RGB: 102 102 102

Comment: That's the official one!

Answer (score 6):

This isn't very easy as there are **MANY** shades in there.

I am getting -

G - Light - #73A2EF Dark - #082463

O - Light - #FF7563 Dark - #AD1400

O - Light - #FFEF08 Dark - #AD8600

G - Light - #73A2EF Dark - #103484

L - Light - #5ACB5A Dark - #085108

E - Light - #FF7563 Dark - #AD1400

(As there are many shades, this is going from the lightest to the darkest that I can find.)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a Mac, the app `/Applications/Utilities/DigitalColor Meter.app` allows you to get hex values for a pixel. If you don't have a Mac, the [ColorZilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/271) addon for Firefox may do the trick for ya.

Answer (score 2):

I recently received email from Google employee with official Google signature that has Google colours in it.

I inspected the html code and got these values from it:

Red: rgb(213,15,37) or Hex #d50f25

Blue: rgb(51,105,232) or Hex #3369e8

Green: rgb(0,153,57) or Hex #009939

Yellow rgb(238,178,17) or Hex #eeb211

Answer (score 2):

By using Photoshop and extracting the colors from the logo of Google I got these values:

- `G` `#156aeb`
- `O` `#da4531`
- `O` `#ffba02`
- `G` `#176dee`
- `L` `#019e5a`
- `E` `#d94530`

Comment: This appears to best represent the current incarnation of Google's logo.